# How can I prevent this button from stretching vertically, and keep it at the bottom of the column?

Tags: html, css

[image]

I have the above form with a submit button on the right side. The button has stretched to match the height of the input boxes PLUS their labels. I want the button to only match the height of the input boxes and be even with them. How can I go about accomplishing that? I have tried inserting an empty div above the button to squash it down and wasn't able to get it to work. I have also tried adjusting the max height of the button but it does not seem to do anything.

Additionally, I am using bootstrap for all my styling, so I would prefer a solution using bootstrap classes, but if that is not possible, then I'll take custom css solutions as well. Thank you.

Here is the html:

```
<form class="mb-5" method="post">
    <fieldset class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label mt-4">Select Client</label>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label mt-4">Select Table</label>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label mt-4">Enter Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary col-1">Load Data</button>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not the cleanest solution probably but can be achieved like so:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.0.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="mb-5" method="post">
    <fieldset class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label">Select Client</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label">Select Table</label>
            <select class="form-control">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label">Enter Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
          <label class="form-label">&nbsp;</label>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control">Load Data</button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove all your `mt-4` classes from your labels and add a `pt-4` class to `<fieldset class="row pt-4">`. Basically moving your positioning class one level up.

Comment: This is good advice, and I just added in your change. However, it doesn't solve the problem at hand, with the button height being the same as the input boxes and their labels.

Answer (score 1):

Placing the button inside a div and giving it class col-1 worked, you might have not removed col-1 from button itself, try this html:
(**do use full page to view it, as the text "load page" is wrapping up that results in increased button height**)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form class="mb-5" method="post">
    <fieldset class="row">
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label mt-4">Select Client</label>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label mt-4">Select Table</label>
            <select class="form-select">
                <option>1</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col">
            <label class="form-label mt-4">Enter Date</label>
            <input type="date" class="form-control">
        </div>
      <div class="col-1 d-flex align-items-end">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Load Data</button>
      </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>
```